# Start Docker with SSL

Tags: ssl, docker, centos

I'm trying to setup a docker application to run on SSL.

How can I start the docker with SSL?

This is to install Tangerine - https://github.com/Tangerine-Community/Tangerine.

The app has a start.sh script that has the following,

```
    #!/usr/bin/env bash

set -v
if [ -f "./config.sh" ]
then
  source ./config.sh
fi


docker pull tangerine/tangerine:$TANGERINE_VERSION
docker stop tangerine-container
docker rm tangerine-container
docker run -d \
  --name tangerine-container \
  --env "T_PROTOCOL=$T_PROTOCOL" \
  --env "T_ADMIN=$T_ADMIN" \
  --env "T_PASS=$T_PASS" \
  --env "T_USER1=$T_USER1" \
  --env "T_USER1_PASSWORD=$T_USER1_PASSWORD" \
  --env "T_HOST_NAME=$T_HOST_NAME" \
  -p 80:80 \
  --volume $(pwd)/data/couchdb/:/var/lib/couchdb \
  --volume $(pwd)/data/media_assets/:/tangerine-server/client/media_assets/ \
  tangerine/tangerine:$TANGERINE_VERSION
```

I tried changing the port to 443 but didn't seem to work.

Is there any other approach that I can use in this case?

Answer (score 0):

The docs indicate `To use SSL, put an SSL enabled Reverse Proxy in front of Tangerine and set the T_PROTOCOL variable in config.sh to https before running start.sh`

So an alternative approach would be to run two docker containers, one as a reverse proxy configured for SSL, and one for tangerine as you have above.

You can use nginx https://hub.docker.com/_/nginx/ for the reverse proxy. You will need to supply the SSL certificate and the nginx configuration to proxy_pass to tangerine. https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/reverse-proxy/

docker-compose can make it easier to run both containers and to link them.